# Can anyone tell me why one of these examples work and the other one doesnt?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently building my own website using jQuery. And i am trying to get an image to shake on hover. I always try effects like this in a "testsheet" before i implement them to my website. In the testsheet everything works fine, but in the main sheet it doesnt.

testsheet:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TEST</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <style>
        #toggle {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: #ccc;
}
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hover above the picture</p>
    <img src="pfeil.png" id="toggle">
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $( "#toggle" ).hover(function() {
            $( "#toggle" ).effect( "shake" );
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

Main sheet HTML:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>JG</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="FINALCSS.css" media="screen"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="PAGE1" class="container-fluid">
        <div id="backgroundDiv1"></div>
        <div id="backgroundDiv2"></div>
        <div id="backgroundDiv3"></div>
        <div style="height:100%" class="row">
            <div id="reihe1"class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div id="reihe2" class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div id="reihe3"class="col-md-6">
                <div id="googleDiv" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="google+"><img id="googleplus" src="google+.png"></div>
                <div id="titel">
                    <p>*******</p>
                    <p>*******</p>
                    <p id="designer">*********</p>
                        <img  src="pfeil.png" id="pfeil">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Main sheet CSS:

```
#pfeil{
    text-align: center;
    width:120px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 250px
}
#reihe3{
background-color: white;
height: 100%;
}
```

Main sheet JS:

```
$(function(){
        $( "#pfeil" ).hover(function() {
            $( "#toggle" ).effect( "shake" );
        });
    });
```

Comment: You are still using "#toggle" for the effect. It looks like you need to change that to "#pfeil" too

Comment: And open your console, you need to include jQuery ui too...

Answer (score 0):

Here is what it should be based on your code:

```
$(function(){
    $( "#pfeil" ).hover(function() {
        $( "#pfeil" ).effect( "shake" );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#pfeil" ).hover(function() {
        $( "#toggle" ).effect( "shake" );
    });
```

Where is your toggle ID in your main sheet HTML ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this `script` tag is missing in your MAIN html file, before `</head>`:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

You might also need a link to your main.js (`<script src="main.js"></script>`) or you need to provide the code before closing body, as you did when testing:

html markup:
`<img src="pfeil.png" id="toggle">`

```
...
<script>
$(function(){
    $( "#toggle" ).hover(function() {
        $( "#toggle" ).effect( "shake" );
    });
});
</script>
</body>
```

Hope to have helped! If I did, please mark this question as useful or correct! Thanks and best of luck.